# What is the use of VERSION file for hadoop.tmp.dir

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

Recently I have formatted namenode and while starting hadoop daemon datanode was failing and giving error as below

> 2019-01-11 10:39:15,449 WARN
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Failed to add storage
>   directory [DISK]file:/app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/data/ java.io.IOException:
>   Incompatible clusterIDs in /app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/data: namenode
>   clusterID = CID-76c39119-061a-4ecf-9de1-3a6610ca57dd; datanode
>   clusterID = CID-90359d7f-b1a5-431e-8035-bc4b9e2ea8b9

As a resolution I have deleted tmp and created again and its working file, also copying the namenode CID to datanode CID in version file it started working.

While looking my backups I can see CID was different for datanode and namenode and that was working earlier.

Can someone provide some detail what each value represent and both CID need to be same or different?

1. storageID=DS-7628c4d7-a508-406c-94fa-9b00f45b4f42
2. clusterID=CID-73f3a584-4a8a-4260-856c-5a2062b6ae61
3. cTime=0
4. datanodeUuid=40834363-2025-4e9a-bb1e-e489bf13cad9
5. storageType=DATA_NODE
6. layoutVersion=-57
7. namespaceID=1181871748
8. clusterID=CID-73f3a584-4a8a-4260-856c-5a2062b6ae61
9. cTime=1547187830726
10. storageType=NAME_NODE
11. blockpoolID=BP-2120424576-127.0.1.1-1547187830726
12. layoutVersion=-63

Comment: I have checked this on different portal : [link](https://www.dezyre.com/questions/5735/what-is-the-use-of-version-file-for-hadoop-tmp-dir) and answer is The Cluster-ID must be same in the datanode as well as namenode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cluster-ID must be same in the datanode as well as namenode Or alternatively delete the `<dfs.datanode.data.dir>` / directory and `<dfs.namenode.name.dir>` / directories and format the name node to start hdfs cluster with fresh copy of cluster ID. You can refer [hadoop tutorial site](http://hadooptutorial.info/incompatible-clusterids/) for more detail

Answer (score 1):

Values present in master VERSION file acts as authentication for datanodes. Only valid datanodes can join the cluster. When datanode joins a cluster it can only be authenticated by values in VERSION file. Hope this clear's your doubt.