# How to restore version file for datanode after formatting namenode

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have executed `hadoop namenode -format` command. Namenode runs just fine, but the datanode cannot start. Version file for datanode shows that it's a NAME_NODE. Before formatting I have deleting everything from /hadoop/hdfs/namenode/* and /hadoop/hdfs/data/*

Now everytime I try to delete everything and re-format the namenode, datanode doesn't get start because of the incorrectly generated VERSION file. Googling didn't yield much.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your version number doesn't match the name node.  The version file is used to see what namenode that the datanode belongs to.  Once they no longer match the datanode doesn't want to join the name node as it believe it belongs to a different namenode.
Here's a [good explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54157642/what-is-the-use-of-version-file-for-hadoop-tmp-dir) of what you need to do.